# How to force a refresh on a URL that it was previously a download link?

Tags: google-chrome

We can force a refresh doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> on a loaded page.

There is a way to bypass the cache on a download link?
Keep in mind that a download link opens on a new tab that suddently disappears.

Initially I had a route that was a download link. When I change that route to be just a page, the browser keeps executing the old download. So I don't know how to clear the cache for that URL.

Imagine you develope a download-file response on `http://example.com/download`.
And one day you change this response to show a page with just some information.
If you have already download the file, the browser remembers this response.

I've tried to clear just the 'browsing history' for that site, but it didn't work.

If I don't want to clear the whole browsing data, which kind of data should I clear to make the browser forgets the old response?

Comment: make a function to call any ajax request on the download link anchor when its clicked and load the download link from a page with cache:false as a parameter. mayb this will help you

Comment: I don't want the download response any more. I was just thinking how to easily clear the cache to get the new page response without changing the url.

Comment: give a dummy random number attached to the download.. that may prevent caching.. provide a onload scrip with an id to anchor tag as document.getElementById("download-provider").href += "?c="+Math.random(0,new Date().getTime());

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1L6jnp7u/

Comment: Thank @AdarshMohan, I understand your solution. Just wondering how to clear the browser caché to get the new response.